# Converting Python List to .NET IEnumerable?

Tags: python, ienumerable, python.net

I'm attempting to call a C# function from a Python script, via the `clr` module from the `PythonNet` library.

One of the arguments that this C# function takes is of the type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`. Simply supplying a list of the required data types to the first argument results in a `'list' value cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'` error.

After searching online, the supposed .NET datatypes should already be included in the Python installation, and I should be able to access them. However, I'm unsure as to how.

Doing:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import *
```

Fails because the module isn't found, while doing:

```
import collections
```

Doesn't have a namespace `IEnumerable`.

How would I go about converting a Python list to the `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` data type?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Which Python module are you using? `clr` is for coloring strings in a terminal...

Comment: Looks like the `pythonnet` package provides a module named `clr`, which isn't related to the package `clr`.

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example. Telling us errors doesn't tell us what you've done or haven't done that could cause that error

Comment: My apologies if I wasn't clear enough, the "clr" module is used for loading external DLL files and accessing their functions. It's from the pythonnet library, and I'm using it to access a set of C# functions. All I would need to know, is how to convert a Python list to a "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" data type.

Comment: My issue can't exactly be reproduced, because I'm using these functions to interface with some hardware, that would be required in order for my script to run.

Comment: @Runsva you should be able to create the same error with a couple of lines of code. See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around in the Python script for a few hours, I managed to figure out a solution:

First, the actual C# `Collections` namespace has to be imported via the `clr` module as such:

```
clr.AddReference("System.Collections")
```

Then, the specific data type of the `Collections` namespace has to be imported:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import IEnumerable
```

And then one should be able to use the respective data type, and call all the class functions it has. In my case, I wanted to convert a Python `List` into the `IEnumerable` datatype. Therefore, I could iterate over my Python `List`, and call the `Add` function of the `IEnumerable` class (using datatype of `int` as an example):

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
myIEnumerable = IEnumerable[int]()

for i in range(len(myList)):
   myIEnumerable.Add(myList[i])
```

As a sidenote, while the C# function that I wanted to call from my Python script has one of its arguments listed as accepting a type of `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`, I managed to get it to work with having a `System.Collections.Generic.List` type instead. Perhaps it'll be useful for someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Before importing anything from C#/.NET you have to `import clr` from `pythonnet` package.